# What does "vertex proper" mean?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I'm working my way through *Graph Reconstruction -- a Survey* by J.A. Bondy and R.L. Hemminger (Journal of Graph Theory, 1:3 (1977) p 227-268) and the terms "vertex proper" and later "edge proper" are used. I have been unable to find the definition of these terms - they seem to have fallen out of use.

My guess would be "vertex proper" = vertex proper subgraph, eg a subgraph with strictly fewer vertices than the graph it is part of. This guess, however, does not correspond to the text which implies that the number of vertices in the vertex proper subgraph may equal those in the graph.

Here is the context (apologies for inability to format properly)

Theorem: Let ***G*** be a recognizable class of graphs, and let ***F*** be any class of graphs such that, for every G in ***G***, each ***F***-subgraph of G is (i) vertex proper; (ii) contained in a unique maximal ***F***-subgraph of G. Then for every F in ***F*** and every G in ***G***, the number of maximal ***F***-subgraphs of G isomorphic to F is reconstructible.

Comment: At least reading over that theorem, the "strictly fewer vertices" meaning seems to make sense. Do you have a quote where that interpretation doesn't work?

Comment: The quote is "By (i) we may assume, without loss of generality, that v(F) < v(G)." Why would we assume and WLOG if we knew it was strictly fewer vertices?

Comment: I read that as "we may assume that $v(F) < v(G)$, because otherwise, $F$ cannot be a $\mathscr F$-subgraph of $G$: (i) tells us that all $\mathscr F$-subgraphs of $G$ are vertex proper and satisfy this condition."

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense